# How to avoid URL encoding in Retrofit?

Tags: android, retrofit, retrofit2, urlencode

I'm using retrofit for my network layer I'm facing a strange issue I've the parameter and it's value look like this

> store://0TxIGQMQbObzvU4Apia0V0&callback=

and after encoding it changes to this

> store://0TxIGQMQbObzvU4Apia0V0%26callback%3D

and for some reason server is not liking this encoding and I'm getting "HTTP 400 Bad Request".

If I hit without encoding it runs fine so I was wondering is there is any way i can disable the endoing.

I've tried other ways like this

```
@Query(value "env" encoded = false) String env
```

but no luck.

This is my network interface class

```
public interface NetworkService
{
    @GET("v1/public/yql")
    Observable<SeriesEntity> getOnGoingSeries(@Query("q") String query,
                                              @Query("format") String format,
                                              @Query("diagnostics") boolean flag,
                                              @Query("env") String env);


    class Factory {
        public  static NetworkService create()
        {
            OkHttpClient.Builder clientBuilder = new OkHttpClient.Builder();
            HttpLoggingInterceptor loggingInterceptor = new HttpLoggingInterceptor();
            loggingInterceptor.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY);
            clientBuilder.addInterceptor(loggingInterceptor);

            Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().disableHtmlEscaping().create();

            Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                    .baseUrl("https://query.yahooapis.com")
                    .client(clientBuilder.build())
                    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                    .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJava2CallAdapterFactory.create())
                    .build();

            return retrofit.create(NetworkService.class);
        }
    }
}
```

**Edit :**

I also notice that the issue is only the encoded value of '&' because if i replace it value (whic is %26) it works fine

Comment: Can you show your retrofit interface, how you're instantiating it, and what full url should be

Comment: @JohnO'Reilly I've added the interface please check

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the issue I believe is that you're including `callback` param as part of `env` one.  Try adding `@Query("callback") boolean callback` to your retrofit interface (and using just `store://0TxIGQMQbObzvU4Apia0V0` for `env`)

Comment: No I'm passing evn as a seperate parameter this my caller 
NetworkService.Factory.create().getOnGoingSeries(QUERY, FORMAT, DIAGNOSTIC, ENV)

Comment: `env` should only contain something like `store://0TxIGQMQbObzvU4Apia0V0` though (going by YQL docs) with `callback` being separate parameter....can you try removing `&callback=` from it and trying

Comment: Thanks man it worked, Oh man I wasted too much time on that :(

Answer (score 19):

Please Use **encoded = true**

@Query(value = "email", encoded = true)

@HTTP(method = "DELETE", path = ApiConstant.DELETE_CONTACT_INFO, hasBody = true)

Observable deleteContactInfo( @Query(value = "email", encoded = true) String email);

Comment: **encoded = true** solved my exact problem, thank you.

Comment: Nice answer! Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

better solution from [Github issue 1199](https://github.com/square/retrofit/issues/1199) , we can have custom interceptor is one way to solve this issue. and this solution work for me.

from your case i want to replace %26 with = in url.

```
OkHttpClient.Builder httpClient = new OkHttpClient.Builder();
httpClient.addInterceptor(new Interceptor() {
    @Override
    public Response intercept(Chain chain) throws IOException {
        Request request = chain.request();
        String string = request.url().toString();
        string = string.replace("%26", "=");
        Request newRequest = new Request.Builder()
                .url(string)
                .build();
        return chain.proceed(newRequest);
    }
});
```

Comment: %26 stands for & , and %3D stands for = sign. [reference](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.ASP)

Answer (score 1):

My problem was that I had a query param that was getting encoded. The only solution that worked for me was adding an interceptor that decodes the URL as shown below:

```
import okhttp3.Interceptor
import okhttp3.Request
import okhttp3.Response
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets
import javax.inject.Singleton

@Singleton
internal object UrlDecoderInterceptor: Interceptor {

    override fun intercept(chain: Interceptor.Chain): Response {
        val original: Request = chain.request()
        var url: String = original.url.toString()
        url = java.net.URLDecoder.decode(url, StandardCharsets.UTF_8.name())
        val requestBuilder: Request.Builder = original.newBuilder().url(url)
        val request: Request = requestBuilder.build()
        return chain.proceed(request)
    }
}
```

You can use this interceptor while creating the okhttp object as shown below:

```
val interceptClient = okHttpClient.newBuilder()
                .addInterceptor(UrlDecoderInterceptor)
                .build()
```

And creating a retrofit builder with this okhttp instance:

```
Retrofit.Builder().client(interceptClient)
                .baseUrl("https://example.net")
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(GsonBuilder().create()))
                .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJava2CallAdapterFactory.create())
```

Works like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

The URL is:

```
https://api.themoviedb.org/3/discover/movie?api_key={"PUTAPIKEYHERE!!!}&with_genres=28
```

I was getting:

```
https://api.themoviedb.org/3/discover/movie?api_key={"PUTAPIKEYHERE!!!}&with_genres%3D=28
```

```
fun getClient(codeForActionOrComedy:Int): MovieDbInterfaceToGetMovies {

        val requestToApiInterceptor=Interceptor { chain ->

            val url =chain.request()
                .url()
                .newBuilder()
                    // ALONE_API is just the "PUTAPIKEYHERE!!!" 
                    .addQueryParameter("api_key","PUTAPIKEYHERE!!!")
                    //codeForActionOrComedy is an Int
                    .addQueryParameter("with_genres","$codeForActionOrComedy")
                    .build()

            val request =chain.request()
                .newBuilder()
                .url(url.toString().replace("%3D","="))
                .build()
            return@Interceptor chain.proceed(request)
        }
        val okHttpClient= OkHttpClient.Builder()
            .addInterceptor(requestToApiInterceptor)
            .connectTimeout(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .build()

        val httpUrl = Retrofit.Builder()
            .client(okHttpClient)
            .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
            .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJava2CallAdapterFactory.create())
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .build()
            .create(MovieDbInterfaceToGetMovies::class.java)

        return httpUrl
}
```

Comment: You had put what appeared to be an actual API key in your sample code. I've removed it, but if that was, in fact, your API key then you should recycle it since it's now part of your answer history.

Comment: Thank you jeremy but that was a made up hard coded api key just for the sake of the example.